# How to drop Google places marker in drawn space

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-places-api

My code is working very fine but there is problem of google places marker it doesnot show any result when i tried to find near by places at my drawn space even it doesnot show any type of exception or error during runtime .This is my code and image can anyone help me out to overcome it

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener,OnTouchListener{

GoogleMap mGoogleMap;   
Spinner mSprPlaceType;  

String[] mPlaceType=null;
String[] mPlaceTypeName=null;

double mLatitude=0;
double mLongitude=0;
double firstlat,firstlong,lastlat,lastlong,cordlat,cordlong;
int index=1;
List<Address> addresses;

//double mLatitude=24.941698263434223;
// double mLongitude=77.44182396680117;
LatLng lastPoint, geoPoint ,firstGeoPoint;

private static final String TAG = "polygon";
private View mMapShelterView;
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
private ArrayList<LatLng> mLatlngs = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
private PolylineOptions mPolylineOptions;
private PolygonOptions mPolygonOptions;
// flag to differentiate whether user is touching to draw or not
private boolean mDrawFinished = false;
private boolean flag=false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

     mMapShelterView = findViewById(R.id.drawer_view);
     mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureListener());
     mMapShelterView.setOnTouchListener(this);
     initilizeMap();

    // Array of place types
    mPlaceType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type);

    // Array of place type names
    mPlaceTypeName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type_name);

    // Creating an array adapter with an array of Place types
    // to populate the spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mPlaceTypeName);

    // Getting reference to the Spinner 
    mSprPlaceType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spr_place_type);

    // Setting adapter on Spinner to set place types
    mSprPlaceType.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button btnFind;

    // Getting reference to Find Button
    btnFind = ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.btn_find);

    // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
   if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    }else { // Google Play Services are available

        // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
        SupportMapFragment fragment = ( SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting Google Map
        mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location From GPS
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location!=null){
             locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
             onLocationChanged(location);

        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

        // Setting click event lister for the find button
        btnFind.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   
                int selectedPosition = mSprPlaceType.getSelectedItemPosition();
                String type = mPlaceType[selectedPosition];
                for(int i=0;i<mLatlngs.size();i++)
                { 
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                //sb.append("location="+mLatitude+","+mLongitude);
                //sb.append("location="+firstlat+","+firstlong);
                sb.append("location="+mLatlngs.get(i).latitude+","+mLatlngs.get(i).longitude);
                System.out.println("D:>> out"+"location="+mLatlngs.get(i).latitude+","+mLatlngs.get(i).longitude);
                sb.append("&radius=50000");
                sb.append("&types="+type);
                sb.append("&sensor=true");
                sb.append("Browser KEY");
                sb.append("&hasNextPage=true");
                sb.append("&nextPage()=true");

            // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download Google place json data 
                PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();                                   

                // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
                placesTask.execute(sb.toString());
                //System.out.println("placestask....."+ placesTask.execute(sb.toString()));


            }
            }
        });

    }       

}


/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);                


            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();                

            // Connecting to url 
            urlConnection.connect();                

            // Reading data from url 
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }

    return data;
}         


/** A class, to download Google Places */
private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    String data = null;

    // Invoked by execute() method of this object
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try{
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
             Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){            
        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
        // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }

}

/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

    JSONObject jObject;

    // Invoked by execute() method of this object
    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;            
        PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
            places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }
        return places;
    }

    // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> list){            
        // Clears all the existing markers 
        //mGoogleMap.clear();
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
             System.out.print("H:>> looping " +i);

            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Getting a place from the places list
            HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);


            // Getting latitude of the place
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));                

            // Getting longitude of the place
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

            // Getting name
            String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

            // Getting vicinity
            String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);

            // Setting the title for the marker. 
            //This will be displayed on taping the marker
            markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);               

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);      
            System.out.println("m..."+ mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions));

        }       

    }

}
 private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
     @Override
     public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
         return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
             float velocityY) {
         return false;
     }
 }

 /**
  * Ontouch event will draw poly line along the touch points
  * 
  */
 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     int X1 = (int) event.getX();
     int Y1 = (int) event.getY();
     Point point = new Point();
     point.x = X1;
     point.y = Y1;
     LatLng firstGeoPoint = mGoogleMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(
             point);
     firstlat=firstGeoPoint.latitude;
     firstlong=firstGeoPoint.longitude;

     Log.d(TAG, "firstgeopoint:"+firstGeoPoint );
     switch (event.getAction()) {

     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         break;

     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
         if (mDrawFinished) {
             X1 = (int) event.getX();
             Y1 = (int) event.getY();
             point = new Point();
             point.x = X1;
             point.y = Y1;
             LatLng geoPoint = mGoogleMap.getProjection()
                     .fromScreenLocation(point);
             mLatlngs.add(geoPoint);

             //geopoint value
             firstlat=geoPoint.latitude;
             firstlong=geoPoint.longitude;


             //last latitude and longitude 
             LatLng lastPoint = mLatlngs.get(mLatlngs.size() - 1);
             lastlat=lastPoint.latitude;
             lastlong=lastPoint.longitude;
             mPolylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
             mPolylineOptions.color(Color.RED);
             mPolylineOptions.width(3);
             mPolylineOptions.addAll(mLatlngs);
             mGoogleMap.addPolyline(mPolylineOptions);
             Log.d(TAG,"geopoint :"+geoPoint);
         }
         break;

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
         Log.d(TAG, "Poinnts array size " + mLatlngs.size());
         mLatlngs.add(firstGeoPoint);
         mGoogleMap.clear();
         mPolylineOptions = null;
         mMapShelterView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
         mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
         mPolygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();
         mPolygonOptions.fillColor(0x7F00FF00);
         mPolygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.RED);
         mPolygonOptions.strokeWidth(5);
         mPolygonOptions.addAll(mLatlngs);
         mGoogleMap.addPolygon(mPolygonOptions);
         mDrawFinished = false;
         Log.d(TAG,"latitude and longitude:"+mLatlngs);

         //looping through coordinates
      /*  for (int i=0;i>=mLatlngs.size();i++){
        LatLng ltln=mLatlngs.get(i);
        cordlat=ltln.latitude;
        cordlong=ltln.longitude;
        }      */         

         break;
     }
     return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
 }

 /**
  * Setting up map
  * 
  */

 private void initilizeMap() {
     int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
             .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
     if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
         if (mGoogleMap == null) {
             mGoogleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                     .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
             mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

         }

     } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)) {
         // showErrorDialog(status);
     } else {
         Toast.makeText(this, "No Support for Google Play Service",
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
 }

 /**
  * Method gets called on tap of draw button, It prepares the screen to draw
  * the polygon
  * 
  * @param view
  */

 public void drawZone(View view) {
     mGoogleMap.clear();
     mLatlngs.clear();
     mPolylineOptions = null;
     mPolygonOptions = null;
     mDrawFinished = true;
     mMapShelterView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
 }

     public synchronized boolean Contains(Location location) {
     boolean isInside = false;
     if (mLatlngs.size() > 0) {
         LatLng lastPoint = mLatlngs.get(mLatlngs.size() - 1);

         double x = location.getLongitude();

         for (LatLng point : mLatlngs) {
             double x1 = lastPoint.longitude;
             double x2 = point.longitude;
             double dx = x2 - x1;

             if (Math.abs(dx) > 180.0) {
                 if (x > 0) {
                     while (x1 < 0)
                         x1 += 360;
                     while (x2 < 0)
                         x2 += 360;
                 } else {
                     while (x1 > 0)
                         x1 -= 360;
                     while (x2 > 0)
                         x2 -= 360;
                 }
                 dx = x2 - x1;
             }

             if ((x1 <= x && x2 > x) || (x1 >= x && x2 < x)) {
                 double grad = (point.latitude - lastPoint.latitude) / dx;
                 double intersectAtLat = lastPoint.latitude
                         + ((x - x1) * grad);

                 if (intersectAtLat > location.getLatitude())
                     isInside = !isInside;
             }
             lastPoint = point;
         }
     }

     return isInside;
 }

    /* public GeoPoint getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress){

         Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
         List<Address> address;
         GeoPoint p1 = null;

         try {
            // address = coder.getFromLocationName(mLatlngs);
             address = coder.getFromLocation(mLatlngs, 10);
             if (address == null) {
                 return null;
             }
             Address location = address.get(0);
             location.getLatitude();
             location.getLongitude();

             p1 = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                               (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));


         }catch(Exception e){
             Log.d(TAG, "exception throw");
         }
         return p1;
         }*/



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);
    //LatLng latLng = new LatLng(firstlat, firstlong);
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

This is my image when i tried to search near by places at my drawn space it doesnot drop any marker there not even showing error can somebody help me out plss....
[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the lat/lon that you used in this example?

Comment: That is the coordinates,
 Arraylist which is appended in google places api
have a look

private ArrayList<LatLng>  mLatlngs= new ArrayList<LatLng>();

Comment: I was able to get `bus_station` locations using lat:19.079006 and lon:73.479959.  See images:  http://i.imgur.com/8JhQTVt.png  and detail: http://i.imgur.com/oWqu5uU.png

Comment: yeah but its hardcoded and i took arraylist of coordinates from drawn space and pass that value on google places api in recurrsion look above code ...   
  for(int i=0;i<mLatlngs.size();i++)
                { 
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
            sb.append("location="+mLatlngs.get(i).latitude+","+mLatlngs.get(i).longitude);
     .....}

Comment: Have you check the `size` of your arraylist in the `onPostExecute` method?

Comment: yup i debug but its get up to loop line but not going inside that loop and even not giving any error and if you talking about its size it depends on the number of places obtain by the marker it means it fetch some data but dont show :(

Answer (score 0):

you can try the new Android Places API, which states,

"If you want to change the place picker's default behavior, you can use the builder to set the initial latitude and longitude bounds of the map displayed by the place picker. Call setLatLngBounds() on the builder, passing in a LatLngBounds to set the initial latitude and longitude bounds. These bounds define an area called the 'viewport'. By default, the viewport is centered on the device's location, with the zoom at city-block level."

https://developers.google.com/places/android/placepicker

You can create a LatLngBounds by using the including(LatLng point) method. See the below page for more details.
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.html

Comment: Thank u harman for help but m stuck to a library of place picker it becomes problem
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;
this one cannot resolved when m trying to use place picker even unsatisfactory result from google for this libraries

Comment: Have you included the google play services library project to your code?